# How best to apply do_shortcode in media.php for captions

Tags: shortcode

I wanted to be able to put shortcodes in an image caption. I've successfully done this by modifying the media.php file with the following just prior to return.

```
$atts['caption']= do_shortcode($atts['caption']);
```

It works great, but I'm sure there is a better approach since I would rather not modify the media.php every time I update WP.

Comment: Related http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113416/nested-shortcode-inside-caption-doesnt-process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caption shortcode attributes are merged with defaults using [`shortcode_atts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/) function  like so (see source in [`media.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/media.php#L836)):

```
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
  'id'  => '',
  'align'   => 'alignnone',
  'width'   => '',
  'caption' => '',
  'class' => '',
), $attr, 'caption' );
```

So the 3rd `$shortcode` param is in use with the value of `'caption'`.

As you can see in [`shortcode_atts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/) source code, it means that the filter

[`"shortcode_atts_caption"`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/shortcode_atts_shortcode/)

will be fired, allowing you to modify the attributes that will be used.

In your case you have to do something like:

```
add_filter("shortcode_atts_caption", function($atts) {
  if (isset($atts['caption'])) {
    $atts['caption'] = do_shortcode($atts['caption']);
  }
  return $atts;
});
```

Please note: if the caption will contain the shortcode `'caption'` this will cause an endless loop.

This can be avoided removing filter before to call `do_shortcode` on caption:

```
function my_caption_shortcode($atts) {
  if (isset($atts['caption'])) {
    // avoid endless loop
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__);
    // apply shortcodes
    $atts['caption'] = do_shortcode($atts['caption']);
    // restore filter
    add_filter(current_filter(), __FUNCTION__);
  }
  return $atts;
}

add_filter("shortcode_atts_caption", "my_caption_shortcode");
```

Comment: I like how you take care of the possibility that the user adds `[caption]` in the caption text.

Comment: Thanks @birgire :) in this specific case is not super-important, but call `do_shortcode` inside a shortcode callback is always dangerous...

Comment: Thank you very much. This answered all my questions and even some I didn't have.