# Forcing max-width for image captions

Tags: shortcode, captions

I've implemented a filter to my image captions based on [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170505/how-best-to-apply-do-shortcode-in-media-php-for-captions) I asked a few days ago. How can I slip into the caption the css style of max-width as well? I think it can be done with preg_replace, but I can't get it to work.

All I really am trying to do is force the image caption text to wrap inside the div.

The default html output looks like...

```
<div id="attachment_1071" style="width: 310px" class="wp-caption alignright">
```

I need it to look like...

```
<div id="attachment_1071" style="width: 310px; max-width:310px;" class="wp-caption alignright">
```

Here is what the filter currently looks like...

```
function my_caption_shortcode($atts) {
  if (isset($atts['caption'])) {
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__);
    $atts['caption'] = do_shortcode($atts['caption']);
    add_filter(current_filter(), __FUNCTION__);
  }
  //preg_replace("/width:{????}px/i", "width:{1}px; max-width:{1}px;", $atts['caption']);
  return $atts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not set `white-space : normal` ?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

without seeing the rest of your css, its hard to determine why the text isn't wrapping naturally

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't work. I have played around with the css a lot and the only thing that seems to work is defining the max-width of this div.

I'm certainly no pro with CSS, I'm convinced it may be black magic, but I haven't found a css solution to the problem. I have a question off to the dev of the theme, but I'm not sure I will get a response.

Comment: could you add the css declarations for wp-caption  and alignright ? That would help.